# Calling function template of class template in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

I have intermediate level of knowledge in C++ and I would like to beg your pardon if you find the question is very easy or not of standard to post in this blog. But, somehow I was unable to solve it.  :)

Your kind help would be appreciated. Here is my code:
The class template is following in a .hpp file:

```
template<typename T>
class FastRetinexFilter{
public:

    static T* getInstance();    
    T Adjust(cv::Mat source, cv::Mat &destination, bool adjustBrightness=true, bool adjustColors=true, int n=3, bool filterOnlyIllumination=false, bool guidedFilter=false, double adjustmentExponent=1.0/2.0, int kernelSize=25, int finalFilterSize=5, double upperBound=255.0);
    ......
    ......
    ......

private:
    .....
    ..... 
    static T *s_instance;
};
```

The definition of the functions are following in a .cpp file

```
#include "FastRetinexFilter.hpp"

using namespace cv;
template <class T> T* FastRetinexFilter<T>::s_instance = 0;

template <class T> T*
FastRetinexFilter<T>:: getInstance() {
    if (!s_instance)
        s_instance = new FastRetinexFilter();

    return s_instance;
}

template <class T> T FastRetinexFilter<T>::Adjust(cv::Mat source, cv::Mat &destination, bool adjustBrightness, bool adjustColors, int n, bool filterOnlyIllumination, bool guidedFilter, double adjustmentExponent, int kernelSize, int finalFilterSize, double upperBound){

    if (adjustBrightness==false && adjustColors==false){
        source.copyTo(destination);
        return;
    }

    cv::Mat gray;
    cvtColor(source, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    ......
    ......
}    
......
......
......
```

Now, I would like to call the adjust function from another class, where I have included the header file and the member of FastRetinexFilter class is properly visible there.

I tried to do it in this manner :

```
FastRetinexFilter::getInstance()->Adjust(colorImgMat, result, brightnessAdjustment, colorCorrection, n, false, gif, a);
```

But it is giving me error. It says that

> "FastRetinexFilter" is not a class, namespace, or enumeration

please suggest how should I can call this function template by using the getInstance() method.

When I don't use the template, the definition is like this. I do like this in other classes, which works fine :

```
FastRetinexFilter* FastRetinexFilter::instance = 0;

    FastRetinexFilter* FastRetinexFilter::getInstance() {
        if (!instance)
            instance = new FastRetinexFilter();

        return instance;
    }


In the header file the declaration is like this :

public:
    static FastRetinexFilter* getInstance();
        ......
        .....
private:
    static FastRetinexFilter* instance;
        ......
        ......
```

To call some function (e.g. connectedComponentLabeling) from this class, I do :

```
FastRetinexFilter::getInstance()->connectedComponentLabeling(binImageCopy,numComponent);
```

But I don't understand, how to do it in the case of templates. 
The function "getInstance()" will return a object pointer of the class FastRetinexFilter. 
So according to your answers, I should do like this :

```
FastRetinexFilter<FastRetinexFilter*>::getInstance()->Adjust(...);
```

But this does not work. 
What should I try ? Please suggest. I need to use template for other functions in the this class. So, it is necessary to use class template and function template here.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the template parameter:

```
FastRetinexFilter<...>::getInstance()->Adjust(...);
                 ^^^^^
             Specify the type
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. I am quite newbie in templates in c++. I just want to call the Adjust function. So for that I need to create one instance of the class but here I call the getInstace() function for generating the instance and through which trying to call Adjust function.

Comment: This approach works well for normal classes and functions but not for the case of templates.

Comment: Please suggests what template parameter, I should mention here ? As the Adjust function does not return anything

Comment: @Spandan Why do you even need a template? Doesn't a normal class work? I didn't specify the type because I have no idea what you were trying to achieve with the template.

Comment: @Spandan what type do you want? `getInstance()` returns the template type `T`, which you have to specify. If you want `getInstance()` to return a `std::string` you would type `FastRetinexFilter<std::string>::getInstance()`. If you wanted the instance to be a class you've created called `Foo` you would type `FastRetinexFilter<Foo>::getInstance()`. This is what Rakete1111 is referring to by "specify the type"

Comment: When I don't use the template, the definition are like this. I do like this in other classes, which works fine :   

 'FastRetinexFilter* FastRetinexFilter::instance = 0;
    
    FastRetinexFilter* FastRetinexFilter::getInstance() {
        if (!instance)
            instance = new FastRetinexFilter();
        
        return instance;
    }'

Comment: In the header file the declaration is like this :

public:
 static FastRetinexFilter* getInstance();
        ......
        .....
private:
 static FastRetinexFilter* instance;
        ......
        ......

Comment: To call some function (e.g. connectedComponentLabeling) from this class, I do :

'FastRetinexFilter::getInstance()->connectedComponentLabeling(binImageCopy,numComponent);'

Comment: But I don't understand, how to do it in the case of templates. 
The function "getInstance()" will return a object pointer of the class FastRetinexFilter. 
So according to your answers, I should do like this :
FastRetinexFilter<FastRetinexFilter*>::getInstance()->Adjust(...);
But this does not work. 
What should I try ? Please suggest. I need to use template for other functions in the this class. So, it is necessary to use class template and function template here.

Comment: Please see the question section, I have explained bit more details